# Using splunk to track memory dumps in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, memory, splunk, perfmon

I'm a beginner and I am wondering if anyone who uses Splunk to monitor SQL server has successfully set up tracking for memory dumps.

As you may know, when a memory dump occurs in SQL Server, a file is created in the root of the SQL server log directory as a .mdmp or .dmp. All we would like to do is be able to keep track of when this memory dump happens and on what server, as indicated by the existence of these files. However, as far as I know, Splunk would not be able to track these files, since it would be scanning a folder looking for new .dmp files, and not indexing a log file that is then searched on.

We have indexes set up for wineventlog, perfmon, and mssql, but to my knowledge, a SQL server memory dump event is not actually logged in any of the related sources types like the general SQL server error log (a related event might, but it would not indicate itself as being related to a memory dump). I might be wrong about this though, and perhaps someone can correct me that this is logged somewhere common that Splunk would be able to consume.

I have also considered that there is a view (sys.dm_server_memory_dumps) that records these events, but we only know of two ways to get that into splunk. One is to set up a sql agent job that would query that table and output it as a file that splunk can then ingest, or to use the sql db connection plugin with splunk, but this has the issue that as far as I know it doesn't use a connection pool, which is a problem for us.

I am wondering how the community has approached this problem, any input appreciated, thank you!

Comment: StackOverflow is more for precise programming questions. I would suggest to ask this in a more server oriented forum: [serverfault](https://serverfault.com) to have a higher chance of people answering. Good luck!